# Setting based login like facebook or twitter in android apps

Tags: android-facebook, android, android-twitter

I have developed an app which uses login credentials to use the app. But I would like to save these in the phone settings like facebook and twitter so that I just have to click on the app to use it and not login everytime. How to do that? Please help. I am able to get the proper words used to search this functionality also :(

Answer (score 2):

You will have to follow the tutorial for ["Creating a Custom Account Type"](http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html), for creating a custom account like the ones used by `Twitter`,`Facebook`, etc.

Alternatively and more easily, maybe you can store in `SharedPreferences` your user's email or `access_token`, or cookie... (depends on your Server authentication), and at your `LoginActivity` startup you just check if those are not null, and you can proceed to the next `Activity`.